# Highlight entire rows based on cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to highlight entire cell values when the row values changes.
For example, row contains

A

A

B

B

B

C

D

E

E

Final result : i want to highlight above the row by means of A has to in one color and B has to be in color and similarly every other values has to be in different colors

Comment: Use this as New Rule,,,  for A,,  `=$A1="A"` ,, then pick cell format of your choice ,,,,  `=$A1="B"` for B,, and so next ,, In case of huge data set VBA macro can be used.

Comment: Please see [**code of @OssieMac** `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2010-conditional-format-color-scale-apply-to/cb92b0b1-d502-4024-b7a4-6185a4d63f06) from October 10, 2013

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve such a problem is to use the Conditional Formatting mechanism by using color scales.

Since this cannot be directly applied to text values (the mechanism only works with numbers), you will need an auxiliary column that will create a unique numeric identifier for each text value. A formula like `=IFERROR(CODE(<cell with text>);"")` seems to be quite suitable for this purpose.

So, create an auxiliary column with this formula (for example, in the F column) and apply conditional formatting to it. To stretch these colors for the entire line, you can use a procedure like this (by @OssieMac):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim rngConditFormat As Range
Dim cel As Range
    With Me
        Set rngConditFormat = .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        For Each cel In rngConditFormat
            cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

If for the auxiliary formula not the F column is chosen, but some other one, then make two changes to the code, where "F" is indicated.

The auxiliary column can be hidden so as not to pollute the data with unnecessary numbers.

[image: Example of result]